# Couldn't find executable named rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following rgbdslam tutorial. I'm using ros groovy and ubuntu 12.04. I have installed rgbdslam using the given steps in http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam. When I run 'rosrun rgbdslam rgbdslam' it gives the following error. Can somebody help?

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rgbdslam below /home/test/ros_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/test/ros_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69751/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-rgbdslam/) by [Cham](https://answers.ros.org/users/5147/cham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you do `rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg`? And if so, what was the output?

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cham](https://answers.ros.org/users/5147/cham/) on 2013-08-18**:
Hello,, Thank you for your response. Yes I did the step that you have mentioned above. It didn't give any error that time. I reinstalled ubuntu and everything is working fine now. Thank you very much.